# windows update is causing my custom service to hang

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

I am using visual studio professional 2015, c# .net framework 4.
I have created a service for windows that sends and receives data on the serial port.  It is intended to start when the computer starts and shutdown when the computer is shutdown.  It should not hang or stop otherwise.

I have been running tests and find that when windows does an update it causes my service to hang.  I have no idea how to debug this hang.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to start tracking down this bug.

thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information like log or something that could help us to understand your problem

Comment: Is normal, if your program depends on some service that is being updated all its dependencies are suspended. To avoid this problem, you can schedule the update at a specific time, or disable it completely and then run it manually

Comment: what log file?  I can give you part of the windows application eventlog showing that the hang occurs when windows update fails

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help.

When I write a service, I typically add an event handler to this `AppDomain` event called `UnhandledException`.

It's sort of a catch-all exception handler and has come in handy on a number of occassions and helps you improve your error handling, in general.

```
// Add this code to the Service Start method or the constructor

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

// Then add this method to your service class, it will be invoked when 
// your code encounters an exception that is not trapped by a try/catch/finally

private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    Trace.TraceError("Unhandled Exception occurred in service: {0}", ex);
}
```

Feel free to replace the `Trace` logging with your own logging framework if necessary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The service doesn't crash.  It just hangs, non-responsive until stopped by the user (through services ).

Comment: That doesn't mean that an exception hasn't occurred